# Exponential inequality derivation

Tags: inequality

If we know that
$$|x-y|<K$$
for $x\leq0$, $y\leq0$ and $K>0$, then what can we say about
$|e^x-e^y|$ in terms of $K$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the mean value theorem and the fact that $e^t\leq 1$ for $t\leq 0$, we obtain $|e^x-e^y|<K$.

Or, if you want a more precise bound, $|e^x-e^y|<e^{\max(x,y)}K$.

Comment: I think you missed something in the first inequality.

Comment: The second inequality is the mean value theorem and it implies the first inequality, since $e^{\max(x,y)}\leq 1$.

Comment: Oh, that's correct, I missed $x,y\leq 0$...